# Graphical anomalies when imports images and updating jLabels / jTextArea

Tags: java, jar, jlabel, jtextpane, graphical-programming

I have an application that whenever I load in any image or update the JTextArea it always places the new object / text in the top left of the frame instead of simply updating whatever object it is supposed to be updating..

[image]
[image]

I am completely dumbfounded to why it is updating the screen in this way, does anyone have any hints or tips as to how to change this?

Below is the code for adding a jLabel into a jTabbedFrame

```
JLabel tempJLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
//tempJLabel.setLocation(1200,1200);
BufferedImage img = scaleImage(getStoredProductImage(photoDir[i]), 190); //scale down found image to whatever is needed
String filename = photoDir[i].getName();
Image tempImage = new Image(img,photoDir[i].getName(),photoDir[i],figureSaveDir(gtinTextBox.getText(), uidTextBox.getText()),tFrame,tempJLabel);       //create ImageObj for later use
if(filename.length()>20){
    tFrame.addTab(photoDir[i].getName().substring(15,19), tempJLabel);
    tempJLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(tempImage.getImg()));
}
```

Unsure if I should also append information of the GUI construction...

Comment: What makes you think we can answer your question without seeing any code? Post your code in the question, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh sorry, though that someone would be able identify the problem from just visually looking at it. i.e. importing the image without setting the location first.. See above for importing images into the program

Comment: Could be a threading issue, or a layout manager issue, or a wrong implementation of a `paint`- or `paintComponent` method. But this sort of guesses won't help you...

Comment: looks strange...im meaning your general tab-layout (why is this called TAB layout?)! what is a JTabbedFrame? Maybe you are just using it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

i assume you just use it in any wrong way.
The ScreenShot of the Tab-Layout looks really strange to me.

But maybe i am wrong (i do not know what a JTabbedFrame is?)

When you mean a **JTabbedPane**, maybe you need to read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html
before using it.